# In the Pycharm "Edit Configurations" dialog the python module name is lost after a search

Tags: pycharm

I have a directory structure:

```
src
    |-- pipelines
       |--  __init__.py
       |--  hercl-parser-pipeline.py
```

I can run the pipeline as:

```
$ python -m pipelines.hercl-parser-pipeline

Processing job outputs from /tmp/jobs//jobs.0509_110602..
```

Inside the `PyCharm`  `Run|Edit Configurations` :

- Set it to "Module" (instead of Script)
- Set the `Working Directory` to the parent directory.
- In the `Module` name I start typing `hercl` and it is found:

[image]

[image]

But when i either double click the full name or hit enter the dialog closes and then the value is *not* copied to the name field in the main dialog

[image]

Why is this happening?

**Update:  I am on `macOS Monterey` with `Pycharm Pro 2021.3.1`
@bad_coder says this does not happen for him on Windows.

Comment: It's working for me on Windows with PyCharm 2022.1, so it's likely a bug (I haven't search JetBrains bugtracker for this).

Comment: Thanks for checking that out. I'll add the O/S info for me (macOS)

Comment: I went through the JetBrains bugtracker and couldn't find any reference to this possible bug, I would advise posting on the bugtracker.